Show that for an affine subspace $M$ over a field $K$ with $char K \neq 2$, we have $\forall p, q, r \in M\quad p - q + r \in M$.

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ with $char K \neq 2$. Let $\emptyset \neq M \subseteq V$ be an affine subspace, i.e. $\forall p,q\in M\quad\forall s\in K\quad sp+(1-s)q\in M$. Prove that $\forall p, q, r\in M\quad p - q + r \in M$.

My proof: $2p + (1 - 2)q = 2p - q \in M$, $2r + (1 - 2)q = 2r - q \in M \implies$$ 2^{-1}(2p - q) + 2^{-1}(2r - q) = p - 2^{-1}q + r - 2^{-1}q = p - 2.2^{-1}q + r = p - q + r \in M$.
Is that ok?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

I posted it solely as a question first, but then I realised that I might have a solution

Your proof is correct. More generally, if $K$ is any field with at least three elements, for any $t\in K$ distinct from $0$ and $1$ we have:
$$p-q+r=t\ \underbrace{\left(\frac1tp+\left(1-\frac1t\right)q\right)}_{\in M}+(1-t)\ \underbrace{\left(-\frac t{1-t}q+\frac1{1-t}r\right)}_{\in M}\in M.$$
Even more generally, for such $K$ and $t$ and for any $\alpha,\beta\in K$,
$$\alpha p+(1-\alpha-\beta)q+\beta r=t\ \underbrace{\left(\frac\alpha tp+\left(1-\frac\alpha t\right)q\right)}_{\in M}+(1-t)\ \underbrace{\left(\left(1-\frac\beta{1-t}\right)q+\frac\beta{1-t}r\right)}_{\in M}\in M.$$
